# UWSGI не видит приложение Django

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

Не понимаю причину, uwsgi не хочет видеть приложение Django. В логах вот что:

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 707|app: -1|req: -1/6] 89.235.190.56 () {38 vars in 585 bytes} [Tue Oct  1 12:31:59 2019] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Адреса приложения и виртуального окружения уже сто раз проверил, вроде все правильно:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /home/kkomissarov/bot/project

# Django wsgi файл
module          = main_app.wsgi

# полный путь к виртуальному окружению
home            = /home/kkomissarov/bot/venv

# общие настройки
# master
master          = true
# максимальное количество процессов
processes       = 10
# полный путь к файлу сокета
socket          = /home/kkomissarov/bot/project/project.sock
# права доступа к файлу сокета
chmod-socket    = 664

# очищать окружение от служебных файлов uwsgi по завершению
vacuum          = true

#Рестарт при обновлении файла
touch-reload    = /home/kkomissarov/bot/log/reload

#Время жизни процессов
max-worker-lifetime = 600
harakiri = 600
```

Как можрно выяснить причину более конкретную что пошло не так?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло указать путь к wsgi не в виде модуля, а виде файла.

То есть в конфиге uwsgi я вместо

```
module = main_app.wsgi
```

прописал

```
wsgi-file = /full/path/to/main_app/wsgi.py
```

К сожалению, я не понял почему вариант с модулем не захотел работать. Я вроде бы ничего не переименовывал, все сделано довольно стандартно, проект почти пустой. Если у кого-то есть этому объяснения - буду рад услышать.